# Order a structure in ColdFusion

Tags: struct, coldfusion

I have a structure in ColdFusion in the format:

```
Jonh        55
Mary        85
Willian     93
Stone       75
Bella       85
```

It has 2 columns with students name on the first column and their score on the second column. How can I order it by the score from the highest to the lowest? If they have the same score, I would like to order by the name.

I'll display it in a table using cfloop. Does anyone know how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: StructSort https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/structsort.html

Comment: This is just an example. In this case my key is the student name and the value their score

Comment: If you have complex data and need additional ordering, consider building the data into a query object [using queryNew](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/querynew.html). Let me know if you need an example and I can make it an answer.